# Different results in c++ using sizeof

Tags: c++, c

I'm facing a strange result `sizeof()` during testing.
How `T1` and `T2` are the same size as the types used in `T2` is smaller than `T1`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct T1 {
    int     id;
    int     enable;
};

struct T2 {
    int     id;
    char    enable;
};


int main() {
    cout << sizeof(T1) << endl; // Print 8
    cout << sizeof(T2) << endl; // Print 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of alignment requirements, padding occurs

Comment: Obviously, `T2` is not in fact smaller than `T1`. Read about [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: Robo upvoters?!? I smell robo upvoters! Let's keep the low research efforts stuff out here please, for sake of the quality of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T2` is padded for alignment.

That is, it contains unused bytes such that an array of `T2` will have all the `T2.id` dword aligned.